# Error: 'sthrow' isn't a type. sthrow ProviderNotFoundException(T, context.widget.runtimeType);

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I have problem when I use bloc.

```
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-6.0.4/lib/src/provider.dart:343:7: Error: 'sthrow' isn't a type.
      sthrow ProviderNotFoundException(T, context.widget.runtimeType);
      ^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-6.0.4/lib/src/provider.dart:343:14: Error: Expected ';' after this.
      sthrow ProviderNotFoundException(T, context.widget.runtimeType);

             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-6.0.4/lib/src/provider.dart:343:41: Error: Expected ')' before this.

      sthrow ProviderNotFoundException(T, context.widget.runtimeType);
                                        ^
2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1159

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

**RouteGenerator.dart**:

```
static Route<dynamic>? onRouteGenerator(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case "/":
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => BlocProvider(
            create: (_) => di.locator<SplashBloc>(),
            child: const SplashScreen(),
          ),
        );
      case "/iws":
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => BlocProvider(
            create: (_) => di.locator<UsersBloc>(),
            child: const InputWellStatus(),
          ),
        );
      case "/login":
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => BlocProvider(
            create: (_) => di.locator<LoginBloc>(),
            child: Login(),
          ),
        );
      case "/iwpt":
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const InputWellProdTest(),
        );
      case "/iss":
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const InputSonologStatus(),
        );
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }
```

I beg you to help me solve this problem.

Comment: You've somehow inadvertently modified files in your `.pub-cache` tree.  I would recommend removing `.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-6.0.4` and running `flutter pub get` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change

```
sthrow ProviderNotFoundException(T, context.widget.runtimeType);
```

to

```
throw ProviderNotFoundException(T, context.widget.runtimeType);
```

Comment: make change where?

Comment: @OMiShah The error message says `sthrow ProviderNotFoundException(T, context.widget.runtimeType);` which means the code is wrong, although the asker never shared the code

Answer (score 1):

change

```
sthrow ProviderNotFoundException(T, context.widget.runtimeType);
```

to

```
throw ProviderNotFoundException(T, context.widget.runtimeType);
```

Comment: make change where?

Comment: remove s in throw